# What is considered 'high traffic' for a Heroku site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, load, traffic

I'm building a Rails application that I plan on deploying to Heroku. The app will be used by a relatively small number of people (wedding website, only ~180 people will be able to see it and interact with it). I was thinking of choosing the Heroku Hobby tier plan, since it's relatively cheap, but I know with traffic spikes, Heroku will bill you more as it scales, and will bounce users depending on how many people are using the app.

I don't think ~180 people would be considered high traffic, but would love to know what people's opinions are on if the hobby tier would be able to handle this without bouncing people, becoming unresponsive, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that the hobby tier would be enough as far as processing power goes, but the gotcha is probably going to be database capacity. Keep in mind that you only get 10,000 rows, which may seem like plenty, but could fill up quickly, depending on how many models you have. It's hard to speak to processing power and computing efficiency without knowing more about your app, but generally speaking, I would think that 512 MB of RAM would be plenty for your needs.

Heroku sites with relatively low traffic tend to feel kind of laggy since dynos shut during periods of inactivity. The first user to hit the site after said period of inactivity will experience lag while a new dyno spins up, so as long as speed and responsiveness expectations aren't too high, you should be able to get by.

If you have any plans of keeping your app around for longer than a month or two, you might consider going with the basic plan. It can be a pain to upgrade databases on Heroku. Experience has taught me to just bite the bullet and go with the basic plan right away. You'll pay a little more up front, but you'll yourself some headaches when you hit 10,000 rows.

Comment: Thanks-- I see that plan is only $2 more/month, so that's still OK. The laggy thing does kind of bother me, too. I wish there was a way around that.

Comment: More traffic will keep the dynos awake :)